# WordPress is not sending emails from Gmail or Yahoo accounts

Tags: php, wordpress, email, gmail, yahoo

I'm using WordPress 4.7.2 and the contact form doesn't send the email if the account of the person is from a Gmail or a Yahoo service.

I'm using WPForms and a default WordPress installation but when I send a message in a simple contact form: Name - Last Name - Email - Message, if I use the contact form as a user with a gmail account or a yahoo account the email is never send, for instance If I use joe@gmail.com the email is not send, but joe@gmai.com works or joe@whateveremailworks.com

Where to begin to look or what could it be the problem? 
Greetings.

Dreamhost - Sharehost - WP 4.7.2

Comment: Maybe -> https://wpforms.com/how-to-fix-wordpress-contact-form-not-sending-email-issue/

Comment: I've used Post man and the Gmail STMP pluging, the problem is that they send the email from the gmail account, and the client is not happy or willing to pay services for sending emails. Anything that not use a paid solution would be great. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful to look for services that allow you to send transactional e-mails. Some offer a free plan.

Examples of these are [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [sparkpost](https://www.sparkpost.com), but there are a lot more. Both have free Wordpress plugins available to make the integration easy for you.

This is just to mention two. I'm **not** affiliated with them and there are a couple of alternatives.

Alternatively, you can configure `sendmail` in your server. Relaying in an external SMTP server not intended to send transactional e-mails can drive you to troubles like the ones you are having now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It looks like the problem is with the anti-spam politics of my hosting provider. Gmail and Yahoo present these spam-problems but you can't let those potential clients to go away, and using and external STMP service to send emails is not a way to go for my client. So after testing I found a workaround in WPForms.

The problem is the sender email? Well let's change that.

Go to the settings of the Form, then go to the Notifications settings and just change the FROM to and email of your host service and that will do the trick. The only down here is that you are not going to receive the email from your potential client so you can't reply directly, you need to start an email and then send it to the user, but over that all the emails and notifications work great without a third party paid service.

Hope this help to anybody. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

For me google stopped receiving e-mails from my own e-mail server (postfix, dovecot, mysql, postfixadmin) to force me to use tls
once i did that i also decreased my spam ability by adding spf, dkim and dmarc to my dns plus signing the e-mails by dkim.